# Swift Actor Hanging - Control over execution not returned after async call

Tags: swift, actor, swift-concurrency

I am experiencing an issue with my actor when I am trying to call another async function that is static and declared to run on the main-actor. Specifically, the called function executes to the end, but never seems to return control over execution to the caller (my actor).

This results in the code after the function call to never be executed.

In simple terms, it looks like the executing MainThread simply "swallows" the return statement.

Below is a minimal example of what my code (structurally) looks like. What actually happens in the called function are `ScreenCaptureKit` calls. I decided to leave them in for clarity.

```swift
actor SomeActor {
  func myTestFunction() async throws {
    print("Before execution")
    let returnValue = try await SomeClass.createSCKSnapshot()
    print("After execution") // this is never called since the previous await never seems to return execution back to SomeActor
  }
}

@MainActor
class SomeClass {
  @MainActor public static func createSCKSnapshot() async throws -> (displays: [SCDisplay], windows: [SCWindow], applications: [SCRunningApplication]) {
    let shareableContent: SCShareableContent = try await SCShareableContent.excludingDesktopWindows(false, onScreenWindowsOnly: false)

    return (shareableContent.displays, shareableContent.windows, shareableContent.applications)
  }
}
```

Now, here you see my actor `SomeActor` trying to call `SomeClass.createSCKSnapshot()` in one of its isolated functions. Thereby, `createSCKSnapshot()` executes just fine including the return statement, but then nothing happens and the `print("After execution")` is never executed inside `SomeActor`.

Why is that? And how can I bypass this issue and ensure that my program continues execution normally after `createSCKSnapshot()` returns?

**EDIT:**

The app **does have** permission and uses ScreenCaptureKit throughout various locations in the app, where everything works fine. The only difference is that code from those locations doesn't call the method from inside an actor but from a class. Therefore, I believe it must be some sort of issue with actors.

Comment: "Therefore, I believe it must be some sort of threading issue with actors." You won't figure it out thinking like that. Actors don't use "threads". You need to think in async/await (Swift concurrency) terms. You should assume the issue is most likely in the chair.

Comment: As for the actual question, the actor in your example serves no function; it is pointless. It is never instantiated and it doesn't have any actor-like functionality.  Can you give a more meaningful example that actually reproduces the issue?

Comment: @matt I am not sure. What information would be needed to make the example more meaningful? `actor SomeActor` used to be a class before where everything worked fine, but now, due to race conditions occurring, we switched to actors to ensure that those are mitigated as good as possible.

Comment: “it must be some sort of issue with actors” … I really don’t think so. When I manifested the problem, eliminating the actor (and this `static` method isolated to the main actor) did nothing to fix the problem. IMHO, it smells like a simple bug in the `excludingDesktopWindows` implementation.

Comment: FWIW, when I did manifest this problem, it went away after a reboot. You?

Comment: Are you certain that the called function on the MainActor is not throwing an exception?  If an exception is thrown then "After Execution" is never going to run because the exception is going to propagate right past it in `myTestFunction`.  What do you get if you add a do...catch in `myTestFunction`

Comment: @ScottThompson yes I am. The issue is related to blocking code on the actor, I will post an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises because there turned out to be blocking code on my actor, never freeing up the actor. Thereby, the function was waiting inside the queue for the actor to free up, which never happened.

If you run in a similar issue, use Xcode Instruments to profile your app and use the "Swift Concurrency" mode to see what work is executed on actors, and what work is waiting in an actor's queue.